# WPF - Reevaluate OneWay Binding

Tags: binding

I have a control whose binding is set as OneWay.

How can I force the value to be re-evaluated in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the binding expression and call [UpdateTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.updatetarget.aspx):

```
BindingExpression binding = Control.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty)
binding.UpdateTarget()
```

Of course, if you implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface on the class that holds the source property for your binding then WPF will handle the updating for you automatically.